# Open command prompt to access folders of a USB connected Android phone

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, command-line

If I connect a Phone with my Windows 7 machine via USB, it shows up in explorer with a name e.g. Nexus 5. How can I open a command prompt and change directory to this device. For lettered drives, I can just type D: F: etc.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In order to assign a drive letter to a removable device, that device must support UMS (USB Mass Storage) protocol.  Unfortunately most newer Android phones, especially those without a removable SD Card, do not support UMS. Instead, they support MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) and PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol) protocols.  In such devices it's not possible to map storage as a drive in Windows.

See more details on this Superuser.com [question](https://superuser.com/questions/369959/how-do-i-access-mtp-devices-on-the-command-line-in-windows).

With that said, on some selected Samsung and Sony Android devices it's possible to enable the UMS mode for external storage only (SD Card).  See [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mohammadag.samsungusbmassstorageenabler&hl=en).

Also, if your goal to simply copy files to and from an Android device via command prompt, ADB will allow you to do so.  This utility is part of [Android SDK tools](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r22.3-windows.exe).  You will need USB drivers for your android phone to be installed, USB Debugging activated in Developer Settings on the phone, and authorize the PC to debug the phone (via a prompt on the device.)  After that is done, you will be able to use `adb push` and `adb pull` commands to copy files & directories, and various Linux shell commands via `adb shell <command>` (e.g. `adb shell ls /sdcard/`) to navigate the directory structure on the phone.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to install a WebDAV server to the android device, then mount the WebDAV server as a drive on Windows 7.
Here is a [free WebDAV server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zq.webdav.app_free) from Google Play (Of course, there are many other WebDAV servers in Google Play). And the [steps to mount the WebDAV server as a drive on Windows 7](http://bestdav.com/mount_drv.htm).

Comment: I found this much easier to do than other answers here (although I appreciate and upvote usable answers). If you use Olive Web Dav, you want to paste the complete supplied URL into the 'Map a Network Drive' option, i.e. `http://192.168.1.136:8080/`, I was up and running in less than 5 minutes, even after trying just the IP, and other varitions first. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it. Unfortunately it is not as easy as it should be.
Follow the instructions here: http://www.7tutorials.com/how-map-drives-windows-7

If you already have the share in File Explorer, for instance after inserting an USB device, right click on the share and select Map Drive and select a drive letter.

Comment: That's for networked devices. There's no mention of mapping USB devices.

Comment: It works the same way - unless Microsoft create yet another way to perform tasks just to confuse people. But I have added some clarification.